# Mongo Instance server failed saying memory resources in docker

Tags: mongodb, yarnpkg-v2

Mongo server failed while running yarn test showing  memory resources error  in docker

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I was using a alpine version of docker. I shifted to the bitnami version after pulling and running of bitnami/mongo:latest